# When a text box contains the <BR/>, Button is not getting clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have web application in ASP.NET

In application I have web page contains a text box for Book Details to entered.

I want user to enter `<BR/>` in that TextBox.

When a text box contains the `<BR/>` string a Button which submit data to server is not getting clicked. I dont want user should enter `&lt BR/ &gt` line in TextBox instead of `<BR/>`

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default ASP.Net will reject any postback that contains anything that looks like XSS.

For instance `<script>alert('xss');</script>` is blocked.

But `<br />` is blocked too, and most sites turn this off - it depends on whether you're using WebForms or MVC.

For **WebForms** add `<pages validateRequest="false">` to the `<system.web>` section of your config or if you only want that page can have a POST with HTML tags, you can also add the `validateRequest="false"` to the top of your asp.net page inside the `<@` directive

For **MVC** add `[ValidateInput(false)]` to your action or controller.